# Semi-hard Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My problem: $\frac{dy}{dx}=2|y(1-y)|^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I distinguished $\frac{dy}{dx}=2\color{red}y(1-y)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\color{red}y(1-y)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. And I was looking for some $z=y^q$ to eliminate an y-factor. Is this the right direction?

Comment: I think it could be easier to consider the integration of $x$ with respect to $y$

Comment: So what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot distinguish the two possibilities as you did, as the value of $y(1-y)$ can be both negative and positive for $one$ function $y$. See, for example, if $y(x) = x$ for $x\in \mathbb R$. This $y$ is an example of a function where neither $|y(1-y)|=y(1-y)$ nor $|y(1-y)|=-y(1-y)$ holds.

Basically, you have an equation $\frac{dy}{dx} =f(x) g(y)$, which you can solve by "multiplying by $dy$" and then integrating, getting
$$\int\frac{1}{g(y)}dy = \int f(x) dx.$$

When you integrate, you will get some equation for $y$ you can (at least in theory) solve.

Comment: So in fact I have to calculate the integral: $\int \! \frac{1}{2|y(1-y)|^\frac{1}{2}}dy$ ? That is a tough one.

Comment: It's not really that hard, just annoying because of the absolute values. But if you have a starting point, an $x_0$, you may narrow down the number of branches you need to inspect.

Comment: Try this one $y=\frac{z^2}{(z+1)^2}$